# Can I copy a build from one world to another on a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I play on a server called WoolCity, and it has multiple servers in one, like Creative, Hub, PVE, etc.
I made a build on Creative that I want to transfer to a server called WCBT, but I can't find how. I was thinking maybe //schematic would work, but I need to be the owner of the server to do that. (which I'm not). What am I supposed to do?

(If this was worded weirdly basically I want to copy and paste a build from one world and put it in another lmao)

Comment: [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1285818-schematica) might help a little. Its still some effort to rebuild stuff, but its a start.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth asking the admin of the particular server to see if they can do it for you. If they can, that's the problem solved. But if not, the only way to copy it from their world would be to copy it to one of yours. If you can get a copy of the world (by asking an admin, but it's unlikely they'll give it to you), you can use a tool like [MCedit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to copy it into another world and keep it for yourself. But it's unlikely they'll let you exchange it between their servers.